# How to disable 'withcredentials' in HTTP header with node.js and Request package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, xmlhttprequest, request

Using node.js and the [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) package from the browser (via [browserify](http://browserify.org/)), I am using CORS to do a HTTP GET request on a separate domain.

On the server, when I set `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to the wildcard `'*'`, I get the following error on the client:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load .... A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is
>   true. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access.

The HTTP request header looks like this:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:withcredentials
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:9966
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:9966/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
```

So clearly the problem is `Access-Control-Request-Headers:withcredentials` in the header, right?

To be able to remove this, I need to set the 'withcredentials' property of the 'XMLHttpRequest' object to 'false'. However, I cannot figure out where node.js or the Request package are creating the 'XMLHttpRequest' object, and how I can even access this.

Thanks.

Comment: It isn't in the docs, but looking at the way `request` uses `http-browserify`, I think you should be able to do `req.withCredentials = false;` before calling `.write` or `.end`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks for your help! It led me in the right direction. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some investigation, I discovered that the `withCredentials` setting can be passed in via the options parameter object:

```
var req = http.request({
    withCredentials: false
}, function(res) {
    //...
});

req.end();
```

If `undefined`, the default setting is `true`.

Reference from the `http-browserify/lib/request.js` source:

```
if (typeof params.withCredentials === 'undefined') {
    params.withCredentials = true;
}

try { xhr.withCredentials = params.withCredentials }
catch (e) {}
```