# Enable to get socket.io file on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I using a angulajs as frontend and node.js REST API as backend both our on different server. I want to use socket.io, but enable to get socket.io.js file on client from the node.js server i  am using

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/node_modules/socket.io/socket.js"></script>
```

to get the socket.io file.

Error:
GET "localhost:3000/node_modules/socket.io/socket.js  "

Comment: Did you take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426882/node-js-socket-io-socket-io-js-not-found) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend taking a look at this library:
  https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io

This way you can easily integrate socket.io with Angular for client side

Comment: I saw that thing it helped me. But now I am getting an error when I try to connect the socket through 
io.connect("http://localhost:3000/")
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412172739903-3. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:1235' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: wait which are you trying to connect to... localhost:3000 or localhost:1235 ?

Comment: 1235(client) to 3000(server)

Comment: I believe this is happening because your trying to connect to another server, one that is different from the one that servers your client. Your basically having a CORs issue. You should look into COrs in general. It is pretty important regarding security. Here are some links that might be helpful: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433099/how-to-disable-withcredentials-in-http-header-with-node-js-and-request-package
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing